# Converting a cURL request to an Axios Post

Tags: http, curl, axios, prometheus

I am working with the prometheus pushgateway library and am having trouble sending information to it. The examples use cURL which work well, but when I try to do the equivalent with AXIOS in my node program it throws an error.

I tried setting up an express server to send the same request to. I wanted to analyze the (REQ) and see how it was displayed. It was mangled by body parser and I am kind of lost.

```sh
  cat <<EOF | curl --data-binary @- http://pushgateway.example.org:9091/metrics/job/some_job/instance/some_instance
  # TYPE some_metric counter
  some_metric{label="val1"} 42
  # TYPE another_metric gauge
  # HELP another_metric Just an example.
  another_metric 2398.283
  EOF
```

I have tried a few different things in axios, none of which have worked
- https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Answer (score -1):

```
       request({
            url: 'http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/interface_data',
            method: 'POST',
            body: 'datahere 10\n',
            encoding: null
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log(response)
                console.log('response, ', response.body)
            }
        })
```

Worked for me. The trick was `encoding: null`